# Query String Preservation in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am newbie of Laravel, PHP and web development. I have two tabs Teachers 
`<a href='/teachers'>Teachers</a>` and Courses `<a href='/courses'>Courses</a>` and two drop-downs i.e. Category, City in header navigation. Teachers and Courses tabs take me to their respective pages `localhost/teachers` and `localhost/courses`. Category and City add query strings as follows by choosing Belgium and O-Levels from their drop-downs.

`localhost/teachers?city=belgium&category=Olevels`

and I want the same query string when I click from one link to to other.

Comment: what are "tabs"? - `Teachers and Courses tabs take me to their respective pages and Category`.. It is very difficult to understand what are you trying to do.

Comment: Post the view which has the tab navigation.

Comment: Two links <a href='/teachers'>Teachers<a/>  and <a href='/courses'>courses<a/> .. and two dropdown menus that will add query strings ?city=Belgium&course=DLD...  I want when i click from Teachers to Courses, the query string remain same...

Comment: Please edit the question, don't add it in the comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to append the query string to the link URLs, using the `Request` facade:

```php
<a href='/teachers?{{ Request::getQueryString() }}'>
    Teachers
<a/>
```

and

```php
<a href='/courses?{{ Request::getQueryString() }}'>
    Courses
<a/>
```